# Can you embed a Swing GUI into a webpage

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, applet

I've made a Swing GUI calculator app at the moment - wrote the code, mashed it all together into a runnable JAR file, and have a nice little icon to top it off too.

My question is this: can you embed a Swing GUI like that into a webpage, or will I need to modify it, or is it a completely different set of rules?

It would be that you could just go to the page and, provided your browser supports Java, the app(let?) would just be there.

I've read that the answer revolves around an applet, I think? I was wondering if this would have ramifications on ditching all of the Swing components I had built.

Thanks for any advice/approaches/answers provided!

Comment: Java Web Start might be something you want to consider looking.

Comment: JApplet is a Swing based applet. Applets run in a security sandbox, so it has a number of limitations, but based on your description, I doubt you'll bang your head against any of them

Comment: *"My question is this: can you embed a Swing GUI like that into a webpage.."*  Don't.  Instead, deploy the Java desktop application from a link on the page using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) as suggested by @yogidilip.

Comment: @yogidilip Could you elaborate on that? Why?

Comment: @AndrewThompson so the result would be that you would go on the webpage, click a link, and the program would run off the browser? Or within the page?

Comment: @MadProgrammer  *"Applets .. has a number of limitations,.."*  I'd call Chrome and FF plans to entirely drop support for applets an huge limitation (to add to all the other difficulties of applet deployment).

Comment: *"..off the browser? Or within the page?"*  Off the browser, which is the best place for them.  A Swing rich client jammed into a web page always had an odd feel to it & quirks to deployment, but in recent times applets have become entirely unworkable.

Comment: @AndrewThompson No argument there, but the op did say *"provided your browser supports applets"* ;)